# Weird Behaviour in Spring MVC when context.xml configured in contextConfigLocation is missing

Tags: java, spring, jetty

We have a Jetty Application which supports JAX RS using Apache CXF and also Spring Controllers. The Jetty server is configured to create a Spring Application Context and also  initialize a Dispatcher Servlet during startup,

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);
....
context.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener());
        context.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation",
                "classpath:/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");
...
ServletHolder cxfServlet = context.addServlet(CXFServlet.class,
                "/services/*");
        cxfServlet.setInitOrder(1);
        
        ServletHolder mvcServlet = context.addServlet(DispatcherServlet.class,
                "/controller/*");
        mvcServlet.setInitOrder(1);
        mvcServlet.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:*/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webContext.xml");
```

The Jetty Server starts without any issue in IDE but when I try to run the shaded jar it fails with the following exception,

```
2023-May-31 17:06:39 PM [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Could not resolve bean definition resource pattern [classpath:*/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:234) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:638) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:632) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:415) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:750) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:313) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:774) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387) ~[jetty-shaded.jar:?]
```

The webContext.xml is not configured in the Classpath and so the above exception makes sense. But Why did it not occur in the IDE?

From the Trace Logs I can find a difference in how Spring tries to resolve the path,

```
[main]  TRACE org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-b3ca52e-servlet', started on Wed May 31 17:04:46 IST 2023, parent: Root WebApplicationContext
[main]  TRACE org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Looking for matching resources in directory tree [/home/<username>/git/jetty-poc/target/classes]
[main]  TRACE org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Searching directory [/home/<username>/git/jetty-poc/target/classes] for files matching pattern [/home/<username>/git/jetty-poc/target/classes/*/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webContext.xml]
[main]  TRACE org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Searching directory [/home/<username>/git/jetty-poc/target/classes/META-INF] for files matching pattern [/home/<username>/git/jetty-poc/target/classes/*/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webContext.xml]
[main]  TRACE org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Searching directory [/home/<username>/git/jetty-poc/target/classes/com] for files matching pattern [/home/<username>/git/jetty-poc/target/classes/*/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webContext.xml]
[main]  TRACE org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Resolved location pattern [classpath:*/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webContext.xml] to resources []
[main]  TRACE org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loaded 0 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath:*/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webContext.xml]
```

Logs from CLI (When trying to run shaded jar)

```
[main] TRACE org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace '
-662ac478-servlet', started on Wed May 31 17:06:39 IST 2023, parent: Root WebApplicationContext
[main] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Could not resolve bean definition resource pattern [classpath:*/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

So just adding a folder to ClassPath somehow changes the Spring Behaviour. Is my assumption correct and any explanation for this behaviour?

EDIT
I'm using Spring 5.2.22.